# Call java main method during maven package

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have main class which scan `classpath` and generates some files. I want maven to call this main method during maven package and place generated files in target directory. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure your `pom.xml` to run some method while executing `package` phase like this -

```
<build>  
 <plugins>  
  <plugin>  
   <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>  
   <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
   <version>1.1.1</version>  
   <executions>  
    <execution>  
     <phase>package</phase>  
     <goals>  
      <goal>java</goal>  
     </goals>  
     <configuration>  
      <mainClass>some.package.where.your.main.Class</mainClass>  
     </configuration>  
    </execution>  
   </executions>  
  </plugin>  
 </plugins>  
</build>
```

After configuring pom.xml you may run the following command -

```
mvn package
```

Now the `package` phase of maven life cycle will execute the `main()` method from the class you have mentioned in `<mainClass> </mainClass>`.

See some other ways at: [3 ways to run Java main from Maven](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/11/3-ways-to-run-java-main-from-maven/)

Comment: Thank you for help. Maven calls my main method but my main method does not work. My main method gets `classpath`, selects some jars from `classpath` and searches all classes which implements some interface. When maven call main method then `System.getProperty( "java.class.path" );` returns `path_to_maven_installation_directory/apache-maven-3.2.3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar` so I modified my method.